# How to use actually use abstract classes/interface in Windows API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, com

I'm aware that there's no actually built-in concepts of interfaces in `C++`, so in order to implement it one must use **abstract classes** which only contains **pure virtual functions**.

Now, In Microsoft Windows' API list, some of the classes there like [`IPropertyStorage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propidl/nn-propidl-ipropertystorage), [`IPropertyStorage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propidl/nn-propidl-ipropertysetstorage), and [`IStorage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-istorage) are interfaces (denoted by the `I` at the start).

Because they are interfaces/abstract classes, they need to be sub-classed or inherited for me to actually use them. What confuses me is that each class have member methods which does certain things, so does that mean I need to override those methods?

**Some of the methods:**
[image]

Thinking that I need to sub-class the Interfaces, I tried the following code below but it seems that I'm wrong about the sub-classing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <propidl.h>
#include <objidl.h>

class PropertyStorage : IPropertyStorage {};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    PropertyStorage ips();   <- function returning abstract class "PropertyStorage" is not allowed

}
```

---

Having said those things, I'd like to reiterate

**My question is:** How do you actually use the interfaces from Microsoft Windows' API?

Comment: You need to implement that function in your class.

Comment: You need to read about COM - looking for a link for you - found one - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/component-object-model--com--portal

Comment: For these specific interfaces there are `StgCreate...` and `StdOpen...` functions in the doc e.g. [StgOpenStorageEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/coml2api/nf-coml2api-stgopenstorageex) that return implementation instance. And you should probably check the [sample applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/samples) they provide.

Comment: I *think* you have misunderstood something fundamental. Why do you think you need to subclass these? API functions return them, and that's all you normally need. (You also seem to not be entirely familiar with abstract classes, so I would recommend reviewing the fundamentals of C++ before diving into the terrifying world of COM interfaces.)

Comment: @molbdnilo That's not strictly correct. There are *loads* of COM interfaces that you would implement in client code. The standard way to do so in C++ is to derive from the interface, and supply implementations.

Comment: @dewaffled Yes, I've seen the stand alone implementation on `IPropertyStorage` and `IPropertySetStorage`, but I'm not sure how can I create a `IStorage` which `StgCreatePropSetStg` needs, anyways those examples sure are very helpful.

Comment: @Eliazar: You don't create an `IStorage` - you cannot, in fact. It's a pure virtual base class. You'd create a derived object - or more likely, have Windows create one for you. I think that `StgCreateStorageEx` does that.

Comment: @Eliazar "*I'm not sure how can I create a `IStorage` which `StgCreatePropSetStg` needs*" - you still have a fundamental misunderstanding of what is actually required. Have you looked at the [StgCreatePropSetStg Sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/stg/stgcreatepropsetstg-sample) yet? You don't create your own class that implements `IStorage`, you ask the API to give you a pre-defined object instead, in this case from `StgCreateStorageEx()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do you actually use the interfaces from Microsoft Windows' API?

That's easy: You acquire a pointer to an interface, and start using it. And when done, you [`Release()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-release) it. That's COM in a nutshell.

On to the harder question then: How do you actually get hold of a [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model) interface pointer? Essentially, there are two ways to do so:

1. Call a factory function that supplies a COM object through an interface pointer. The "standard" way is by calling [`CoCreateInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance). The less "standard" (albeit increasingly common) way is to call a dedicated factory function. To get an [`IPropertyStorage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/propidl/nn-propidl-ipropertystorage) interface you can call [`StgCreatePropStg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/coml2api/nf-coml2api-stgcreatepropstg) (or similar), for example.

   This addresses the use case where you are consuming a COM interface that the system (or a library) provides for client use.
2. Implement the interface, and use whatever means you see fit to instantiate this concrete implementation. When using a COM-capable C++ compiler (such as MSVC) this amounts to providing an implementation for a class that derives from the interface.

   This is useful for cases where you need to author an interface, generally to be consumed by someone else. Examples include `IStream` or `IEnumString`. This is not the case for the interfaces asked for in the question.